# emails from iDRAC6 express are failing

Tags: email, dell, drac

I have Dell R710 servers with iDRAC6 express.  There is no dedicated NIC for the drac, so in the NIC selection it is set to shared.  The IP, subnet, DNS and gateway are all good and the domain name is set to the DNS domain name.  The server is running esxi 5.5 so the 4 NICs are all part of the VMWare NIC group.  In the System --> Alerts --> Email alert settings page i put in my email address and try to send a test email and i get back a message that the test failed.  I have tried using the ISP mail server which has worked for me with other clients in the past as well as tried using their internal SMTP server.  I have verified relay permissions on the local SMTP server and made sure no firewall rules are blocking smtp for trying to use the ISP smtp server.

When trying to set the alerting VIA OMSA, i get no options for email alerts and this message is displayed for the alert actions information" This feature is not available on this system due to operating system or hardware limitations. Refer to the online help for more information"

Does anybody have any idea what could be going on here?  I'm starting to wonder if iDRAC6 express just wont send out email alerts or if it could be something with the shared NIC and vmware.

Comment: OK, the DRAC IP is 10.10.10.81/24, the gateway is 10.10.10.10.  The DNS servers are .2 and .3.  I am using a public SMTP server that i am able to telnet on port 25 from the server.  I have also tried using the internal SMTP server here and can also telnet to port 25 on that as well.  I am currently rebooting the server now, but when it comes back up i will send the test email out through telnet.

Answer (score 0):

Brian,
Without knowing any details at all, here's what I would do to test.

Assumptions:

```
DNS:
example.com in mx mx.example.com ;(we'll say spam filter that forwards to smtp.example.com)
mx.example.com. in A 10.0.0.125
example.com. in TXT "v=spf1 10.0.0.0/24 ~all"
mx.example.com. in TXT "v=spf1 a -all"
idrac.example.com. in TXT "v=spf1 a -all"


125.0.0.10.in.arpa-addr. in ptr mx.example.com.
10.0.0.10.in.arpa-addr. in ptr idrac.example.com.
```

Records:

```
idrac.example.com = 10.0.0.10
smtp.example.com = 10.0.0.25
mx.example.com = 10.0.0.125
```

idrac settings:
from:notify@idrac.example.com
to:mailbox@example.com
hostname:idrac.example.com

can you telnet to 10.0.0.125 from 10.0.0.10 on port 25? (hook up a laptop)

```
telnet 10.0.0.125 25
ehlo idrac.example.com
mail from:notify@idrac.example.com
rcpt to:mailbox@example.com
data
subject:Test Message
This is a test
.
```

(return twice)

more specific information would be helpful.